# Format an integer like a timezone offset (ex. +02:00)

Tags: c#

I have a number between -12 and 12. How can I get it in this format: "+number:00"

Ex. for -4: -04:00

Ex. for 10: +10:00

Comment: what have you tried so far, which problems have you encountered?
what is the input type, what is the output type?

Comment: I tried building it part by part, but maybe there's a way with string formats?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you have a DateTimeOffset value, formatting it with an offset is already available. Integers can't represent half-hour timezones (India, +5:30, big timezone). A *Timespan* on the other hand is far more appropriate

Comment: Irrelevant to my question. You can even forget about timezones. All I need to know is how do I turn an integer into that format.

Comment: @Angelo by using the relevant types. Create a TimeSpan from the number and format it with `ToString()`

Comment: Did you try using a format string in `.ToString()`?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings  The most relevant questions here are what did you try and what isn't working?

Comment: I built it part by part (adding strings) and it worked (obviously), and I wanted to know if there's fancier ways, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more precise

```
number.ToString("+00;-00") + ":00"
-OR-
number.ToString("+00':00';-00':00'")

-4 --> -04:00
10 --> +10:00
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The title of the question starts "Format an integer..." and in comments the OP said "You can even forget about timezones. All I need to know is how do I turn an integer into that format"

Comment: I'm not trying to do his work or think for him, just answering the question.

Comment: Yes this is fine, I accepted the first answer for the broader explanation

Comment: @Angelo just in case: what you accepted doesn't work the way you need :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just concerned about formatting the number to particular format with signs (positive/negative), you could

```
var positive = 5;
var negative = -12;
var strPositive = positive.ToString("+00':00';-0#':00'");
var strNegative = negative.ToString("+00':00';-0#':00'");
```

Output

```
+05:00
-12:00
```

You are making use of Conditional Formatting here. You can read more on the same [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Quoting.

> The semicolon (;) is a conditional format specifier that applies
>   different formatting to a number depending on whether its value is
>   positive, negative, or zero

For a format string with two sections

> The first section applies to positive values and zeros, and the second
>   section applies to negative values.
>
> If the number to be formatted is negative, but becomes zero after
>   rounding according to the format in the second section, the resulting
>   zero is formatted according to the first section.

Comment: "00.00" not "0.00" I guess, he wanted `-05:00`

Comment: @ArthurRey It uses conditional formating of numbers. I have updated the answer with explanaiton

Comment: Interesting but I need ":" instead of "."

Comment: How will that work with India's timezone? The correct type for offsets is Timespan, in fact, that's what [DateTimeOffset.Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.offset?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns. Timespan custom formats don't have sections but the `c` format can be truncated,eg : `TimeSpan.FromHours(5.5).ToString("c").Substring(0,5)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree, which is why I had started the answer with "If OP is only interested with numbers" (which incidentally he mentioned in a comment)

Comment: @AnuViswan that does't work `:` is format specifier. you have to escape entire sequence - like in my second example. Your current code produces e.g. `+00:10` for 10

Comment: Following Mike comment : https://rextester.com/PWWLR82843 . The `:` break the formating

Comment: well I trusted your output but it looks like you were wrong, it takes it from the end

Comment: @MikeMakarov Thanks for pointing out. Rightfully, yours is marked as Answer. For sake of completion, I would like to borrow your quotes. But what I do not get is why the escape character "\" doesnt work in this scenario

Comment: @AnuViswan You have to escape not only `:` but also following `0`es, like so `+00\:\0\0;` - this worked for me but was way to cumbersome :)